# Yii2: check method availability with is_callable method

Tags: php, yii2

I need to check availability of method `getRecipients` in class `Interaction`, and i have some troubles which i don't understand.

When i try to check method availability, i tried to do this two ways, which seems quite similar for me, and they return different values (nb: method are not exists so second way return exactly what i need):

```
var_dump(is_callable([$event->sender, 'getRecipients'])); // return true
var_dump(is_callable([get_class($event->sender), 'getRecipients'])); // return false
```

$event->sender have an object of class `Interaction`

```
object(app\\models\\Interaction)#1121 (8) {...}
```

So, why are they returned different values, and is that normal to use something like `is_callable([get_class($event->sender) ...])`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `ActiveRecord`/`Model` implements [`__call()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) magic method (at [`Component` level](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/3d96a45f6b2ded171c607e20b9f3e39a618ab9cb/framework/base/Component.php#L279-L301)). At this point PHP assumes that any method can be called non-statically on this class. But this does not affect static calls (which has its own [`__callStatic()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.callstatic) magic method).

- **`is_callable([$event->sender, 'getRecipients'])`** checking for possibility non-statically call (which is always possible, because class implements `__call()`).
- **`is_callable([get_class($event->sender), 'getRecipients'])`** checking for possibility statically call (which is not possible, because `__callStatic()` is not implemented and `__call()` has no effect on static calls).

The same rules applies for `__callStatic()`:

```
class Interaction {

    public function __call($name, $params) {
    }
}

class StaticInteraction {

    public static function __callStatic($name, $params) {
    }
}

$interaction = new Interaction();
$staticInteraction = new StaticInteraction();

var_dump([
    is_callable(['Interaction', 'getRecipients']), // false
    is_callable([$interaction, 'getRecipients']), // true
    is_callable(['StaticInteraction', 'getRecipients']), // true
    is_callable([$staticInteraction, 'getRecipients']), // false
]);
```

https://3v4l.org/lQW9A

---

For checking if class has method you should use [`method_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php) or [`hasMethod()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-component#hasMethod()-detail) (this will include methods from behaviors).